# Is this possible? Specify any generic type as long as the + operation is defined on it

Tags: c#, types, operators, .net-generic-math

**I'm not sure if this is possible, but if it is then it would be useful.**

I am attempting to program in a class called `Matrix<T>`. The intent is to be able to have matrices of various data types, such as integers, floats, doubles, etc.

I now want to define addition:

```
    public static Matrix<T> operator +(Matrix<T> first, Matrix<T> second)
    {
        if (first.dimension != second.dimension)
        {
            throw new Exception("The matrices' dimensions do not match");
        }
        Matrix<T> add = new Matrix<T>(first.dimension);

        for (int i = 1; i <= first.rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= first.columns; i++)
            {
                add[i,j] = first[i,j] + second[i,j];
            }
        }
        return add;
    }
```

There is an issue with the line `add[i,j] = first[i,j] + second[i,j];` since the operation `+` is not defined on a general object of type `T`.

I only want to specify matrices where `T` is a type such that addition is defined, however. So, I can make a matrix of `int`s, `float`s, `double`s, etc. but if I were to try and define a matrix of, say, `int[]`s, I would want this to throw an exception since `+` is not defined for `int[]`s.

**So, instead of writing `T`, is there some way of telling the computer "this can take in any generic type, as long as an operator `+` is defined on the type? Or, is this not possible and I would have to sepeately define a matrix of `int`s, matrix of `float`s, and so on?**

Edit: I don't see how [the linked question from closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70037614/c-sharp-how-to-require-a-const-static-readonly-field-of-generic-type-parameter) is related to this - I see nothing about operators there. If they are related, can somebody explain how?

Comment: I think, generic math may help here (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/), but this is only in preview for now. For a ordinal C# generics there is no way to achieve this.

Comment: It would me nice if there was an INumeric (or something like that) to use a constraint. But as far as I know, there isn't. We finally got a `System.Enum` constraint, we can hope

Comment: I don't see how the linked question from closure is related to this - I see nothing about operators there. If they are related, can somebody explain how?

Comment: With preview feature enabled you can use [`IAdditionOperators`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/af4efb1936b407ca5f4576e81484cf5687b79a26/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IAdditionOperators.cs#L17)

Comment: @Serg, Guru Stron that does look like what I need - thank you. I haven't used preview features before but I will investigate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible (at least without losing compile time safety or changing the API) but with preview features enabled and `System.Runtime.Experimental` nuget you can use [`IAdditionOperators`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/af4efb1936b407ca5f4576e81484cf5687b79a26/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IAdditionOperators.cs#L17) to restrict `T` to have `+` operator defined. I would say that adding this interface also to `Matrix` itself can be a good idea:

```
class Matrix<T> : IAdditionOperators<Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>> where T : IAdditionOperators<T, T, T>
{
   public static Matrix<T> operator +(Matrix<T> left, Matrix<T> right)
    {
        // swap to real implementation here
        T x = default;
        T y = default;
        Console.WriteLine(x + y);
        return default;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Generic math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/) (especially [section](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/#trying-out-the-features) about trying it out, note - VS 2022 recommended)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using reflection

```
class Int
{
    readonly int v;

    public int Get => v;

    public Int(int v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public static Int operator +(Int me, Int other) => new Int(me.v + other.v);
}


class Arr<T>
{
    T[] _arr;

    public Arr(T[] arr)
    {
        _arr = arr;
    }

    public T this[int index] => _arr[index];

    public static Arr<T> operator+(Arr<T> me, Arr<T> other)
    {
        var addMethod = typeof(T).GetMethod("op_Addition");
        if (addMethod == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type {typeof(T)} doesn't implement '+' operator");
        var result = me._arr.Zip(other._arr)
            .Select(elements => addMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { elements.First, elements.Second }))
            .Cast<T>()
            .ToArray();
        return new Arr<T>(result);
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestAdd()
{
    var firstArray = new Arr<Int>(new[] { new Int(1), new Int(2) });
    var secondArray = new Arr<Int>(new[] { new Int(2), new Int(3) });
    var sum = firstArray + secondArray;
    Assert.AreEqual(3, sum[0].Get);
    Assert.AreEqual(5, sum[1].Get);
}
```

Reduced the example to array.
Unfortunetly it compiles even if T doesn't implement add operator, so you will get a  exception in runtime. You could also check if the add method has proper signature (returns T and takes two T's). If you need help understanding the code, let me know!